# Basic SQL Query Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please help me write this without using IN ?

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM author
WHERE authorid IN (
SELECT authorid
FROM published_by JOIN written_by
ON written_by.bookdescid = published_by.bookdescid
WHERE  publisherid IN (3,746)
AND NOT written_by.role LIKE ('%translator%')
AND NOT published_by.role LIKE ('%editor%')
);
```

Struggling a bit here for a new SQL without using IN

Many thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using `IN`?

Comment: Nothing, I am working through some examples where the first one asks you to use an IN subquery then the second one just says JOIN without the IN. I'm trying to expand my skills but can't seem to get it to work without the IN subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE  publisherid IN (3,746)
```

is the same as

```
WHERE  (publisherid = 3 OR publisherid = 746)
```

Oops, I just saw there is another `IN` clause in your query :-)

`IN` is perfect in this context. You can use EXISTS instead, if you like that better (I don't):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM author a
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM published_by p
  JOIN written_by  w ON w.bookdescid = p.bookdescid
  WHERE p.publisherid IN (3,746)
  AND NOT w.role LIKE ('%translator%')
  AND NOT p.role LIKE ('%editor%')
  AND w.authorid = a.authorid
);
```

Comment: to add another layer, is it possible to write this query without a JOIN? Only using IN subquery

Comment: Yes. `select ... from author where author_id in (select author_id from written_by  where bookdescid in (select bookdescid from published_by ...`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.firstname, a.lastname
FROM author a
INNER JOIN published_by p
  ON a.authorid = p.authorid
INNER JOIN written_by w
  ON w.bookdescid = p.bookdescid
WHERE publisherid IN (3,746)
  AND NOT w.role LIKE ('%translator%')
  AND NOT p.role LIKE ('%editor%')
```

Although not sure why you want to avoid it, personally I think original query is clearer

Comment: I agree. While it is possible to join here, `IN` (or `EXISTS` for that matter) is much better than to create an unnecessarily large intermediate result one must then get rid of with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. I think your EXISTS query Thorsten is great. For some reason this one Milney isn't returning any results. I agree IN is the best for this situation but im trying to teach myself about various different operations so it's about understanding different options. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah I mean I'm not saying this is the right way to do - I totally agree EXISTS and IN are better, just adding some options. About the no results - I guess your author id is called authorid not just id and you have a surrogate key, editing it now should work

Comment: Ah awesome mate, thanks again. I've actually got another one i've been struggling with as well so will post that in a few mins

Comment: I suppose you got the joins wrong. `authorid` is probably a column in `written_by` and not in `published_by`. @kieranharrison: Don't you get an error when running this query?